# AzureDevops - ##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '-2146893802'

Tags: c#, angular, azure, azure-devops, publish

When I release a pipeline, this error appears:

> ERROR ( hresult:80090016, message:Failed to commit configuration changes.
> Keyset does not exist )
> ##[error]Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '-2146893802'.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot of error message]

I do not know what else to do. I've followed some tutorials, but still nothing.

The idea is to publish the system in the approval and production environments. I use VPN to access the folder environment.
The worst thing is that I did several tests and it was working normally, but after 1 month it started giving this error and I haven't been able to solve it yet.

I tried to include LocalService in the permissions, as per the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/0x80090016-change-application-pool-identity

but still nothing.

Comment: Thanks for mostly translating. Please consider also providing a translation of the error message. Itmakes sense to also keep the original in that case.

Comment: According to my understanding, this pipeline was working before and then suddenly started to fail.  If it's correct, do you make any changes in your pipeline? If not, the issue may be related to your IIS web app. You can deploy from your local machine. If it works, investigate further in your pipeline. If it doesn't work, you need to check your app. According to [this blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/keyset-does-not-exist-exception-from-hresult-0x8009000d-or-or/ba-p/342955), you may have this issue when your IIS specific machine keys are corrupt or missing.

Comment: Exactly, it worked perfectly, but suddenly it stopped.
I didn't make any changes to the pipeline, but the company had a change of physical location and the server also changed, there may have been some configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Ziyang Liu-MSFT. This issue might occur due to the corrupted machine key.

One way to resolve this issue is to regenerate new Machine key and add it in your Web.config by referring this [**blog**](https://www.technomark.in/How-To-Generate-Machine-Key-In-IIS.aspx#)

Or to generate the machine key use the command below in your local Web app hosted in IIS:-

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "system.web/machineKey" C:\path\path\WebApplication16
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Now, ***Update your web app > web.config with the generated keys above***:-

```xml
<system.web>
  <machineKey validationKey="ValidationKey" decryptionKey="DecryptionKey" validation="SHA1" />
</system.web>
```

Make sure [Application Pool Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) has necessary permissions on the machine key and web app configurations.

[image]

After you update your machine key and configuration, Restart your IIS Web server and then run the Release pipeline again:-

```bash
iisreset
iisreset /restart
```

If none of the above steps resolves the issue, Raise an [Azure support request](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket) or a query in this [Forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-devops/bd-p/AzureDevOpsForum).