IIS web application deployment error, How to resolve?
How can I resolve this IIS web application deployment error?

C:\azagent\A2\_work\_tasks\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup_1b2aec60-dc49-11e6-9b76-63056e018cac\0.238.0\IISWebAppManagementOnMachineGroup.ps1: Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '-2146893802'.
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '-2146893802'.

Process 'appcmd.exe' exited with code '-2146893802'.


Please check this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77230355/azuredevops-errorprocess-appcmd-exe-exited-with-code-2146893802

How do you configure the IIS web app manage task in your pipeline. With the same configurations, did this task work fine before? Did you try manually logon the agent machine to execute the IIS deployment? Does the the issue occur? As mentioned in above link, you can try to regenerate new Machine key and add it in your Web.config file to see if the issue can be fix.
